# How to correctyle use namespace in php

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm trying to use the PHP zendesk API in my application. It's in folder

```
Library/Zendesk/API
```

The classes are namespaced:

```
namespace Zendesk\API;
```

To invoke I use:

```
use Library\Zendesk\API\Client as ZendeskAPI;
$client = new ZendeskAPI($subdomain, $username);
```

Which gives a class not found error (checked - Zendesk\API\Client.php is included). It's fixed when I edit Zendesk\API\Client.php and change namespace to

```
namespace Library\Zendesk\API;
```

Doesn't seem like the right way to go. Any tips on the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

From PHP documentation [how to correctly use namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.nested.php) and [namespace nested](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.nested.php)

the correct format is with  `\`

```
namespace MyProject\Sub\Level;
```

Comment: Yes, thats what I'm using. Problem is that in the zendesk script 'namespace Zendesk\API;' is used (see source at https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_api_client_php/blob/v1/src/Zendesk/API/Client.php). The classes are then included but not found. If I alter to namespace Library\Zendesk\API it works - but I don't want to change the zendesk files.